# Assume $f$ is differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$, $f(0) = 5$ and $\forall x, f’(x) \neq 0$. Prove $f(x) \neq 5, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

[image]

The problem with my solution is that it only works for small values of h. How would I account for large values of h?

Comment: This is false, since $f(0)=5$.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the mean value theorem?  If you have two points where $f(x)$ is 5 (one of the points being $f(0)$) then there would have to be a point between them with the same slope as the line from $(0,5)$ and $(x,5)$, which is zero.  But you know the slope can never be zero.

Or, you know, better put, Rolle's Theorem, a special case of MVT that applies directly to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that any function which is a derivative of another one satisfies the intermediate property even if it is not continuous! So, if this function $f$ is such that $f'(0)>0$ for example, then it should be $>0$ everywhere, otherwise, if it is not so, it should be $<0$ at some $x_0$ (Recall that the derivative is never zero by hypothesis) but this implies that the derivative is zero between 0 and this point $x_0$ because of the intermediate property. QED